# SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS + zf2

Tags: zend-framework2, sql-calc-found-rows

I am using a simple select statement using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in zf2. The code would look like as follows and uses quantifier.

```
$select = $this->getSlaveSql()->select('posts');
$select->quantifier(new Expression('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS'));
$select->columns([
       'total'=>new Expression("FOUND_ROWS()"),
       '*'
]);
```

And the generated sql is as below

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FOUND_ROWS() AS `total`, `posts`.* FROM `posts`
```

screenshot:
[image]

But for some reasons, found_rows is always returned as 0 and I do not want to add a second query for pagination. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FOUND_ROWS()` is normally used in a subsequent query. I doubt you can run it in the same one that you select data in. See the example in the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Also note that `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` makes no sense in a query without a limit.

Comment: I have the same problem with limit too. Using SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FOUND_ROWS() AS `total`, `posts`.* FROM `posts` LIMIT '10' also have no effect :(

Comment: Well, like I said, the `FOUND_ROWS()` call needs to be in a separate query after you've selected the posts data.

Comment: thanks tim, the problem is solved using another select query for the found_rows(), as you said.